# Laravel - Array get attribute

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-5

I'm working on something which requires me to get an attribute from an array, Which I thought was fairly simple.  Weirdly I can't figure out how to get the attribute. The attributes that I need to achieve is the IP address in an array. If I dumpDie the object it returns the following

```
0 => Networks{#1010 ▼
  +ipAddress: "192.125.3.232"
  +gateway: "192.125.0.1"
  +type: "public"
  etc......
```

Now I need to receive the IP address from this array. How can I achieve that?

I've tried doing things like

`$data['networks'][0]['ipAddress'];` or `$data->{'networks[0]'}->{'ipAddress'}`

But both of them gave the error

`Cannot use object of type DigitalOceanV2\Entity\Droplet as array`

What is the solution to this problem?

**EDIT**

I get the object doing this

```
$droplet = DigitalOcean::droplet()->create($storeName, 'ams3', 's-1vcpu-1gb', $images[0]->id);

$data = DigitalOcean::droplet()->getById($droplet->id);
```

Comment: Networks is capitalized.

Comment: @Adam That doesn't make a difference otherwise I wouldn't have posted the question. I've tried that already.

Comment: Can you give us a complete dump of the array in question then?

Comment: @SougataBose Unfortunately that does not work. It gives me the same error stated above.

Comment: @Adam The complete dump is this https://imgur.com/a/QUfTa

Comment: Please show the code how you get **$data**?

Comment: @ChiragPatel I updated the question

Comment: The error says that `Networks` is not an array.. get the props like an object. `$data->networks[0]->ipAddress`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But both of them gave the error
>
> `Cannot use object of type DigitalOceanV2\Entity\Droplet as array`

Because Droplet is an object, so you need to use `->` to get the properties.

`$data->networks[0]->ipAddress`

Answer (score 1):

Try this code,
First check that you have values in **`$networks`** by,

```
$networks = $data['networks'];
```

And if **`$networks`** is not empty, Try this

```
$ipAddress = $networks[0]['ipAddress'];
```

Comment: That gives me the error `Cannot use object of type DigitalOceanV2\Entity\Droplet as array`. I don't understand this at all

Comment: Can you use this `$data = DigitalOcean::droplet()->find($droplet->id);` instead of using **getById** ? and check the result it's coming or not?

Comment: It gives me the same error as the first comment on this question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168563/discussion-between-chirag-patel-and-rainier-laan).